# How often will Python make a mistake?

Tags: python, architecture

I've recently been amazed running a code that takes hours to run with many processes and arrives at the exact same numerical result every time. Maybe it's just me anthropomorphizing the computer, but it seems impressive.

By mistake I mean a result of a program that is not what it should be based on the initial conditions and the rules of the language. This would have to be caused by a random error, maybe cosmic radiation noise or something. I'm talking 2+2=5, not a human writing bad code. Something where, if you ran it again, with the same code and initial conditions, it would give the correct result (assuming the error was unlikely but not impossible).

I know this sort of thing is possible in computers ([How often do computers make mistakes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923413/how-often-do-computers-make-mistakes)), but it sounds like it is unlikely. So is there any sort of redundancy built into Python itself or is that built in on a deeper level? And how many floating point operations can be done before you can expect one to be incorrect?

Bonus: What about other languages? Are there some that are more reliable in this sense than others?

Comment: At the end of the day, computers are deterministic. You mentioned floating-point operations, and how their errors can accumulate, but on a given system the same floating-point operation will always produce the same result - the errors produced by them only become relevant when you've got multiple systems and you're trying to reach a consensus. The only way they could "screw up", as far as I'm currently able to imagine, is, like you were saying, through some failure of hardware or an external force (radiation, etc.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm wondering about- a mistake from thermal noise, quantum effects, radiation noise, etc, like talked about in the link. How common is this? And what kind of redundancy exists to combat it?

Comment: @ThomasDewitt I actually saw a relatively new video from Veritasium who was talking about it really nicely. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaZ_RSt0KP8&ab_channel=Veritasium

Comment: There is no redundancy at all built in to python to combat bit errors. The link you supplied provides information for the remainder of your question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question. The far more likely issue is that your code simply has bugs in it, but we can't help you fix those bugs if you assume it's a problem with the language or hardware (both extremely less likely).

Comment: @Chris, it's a programming question because I want to know if this is ever a problem and if it is it would be very nice to know. I don't have malfunctioning code, in fact I'm just amazed it never makes a mistake as I mentioned. So I'm not trying to fix a problem; I'm trying to understand how Python works.

Comment: @Leemosh, very good video and helpful thanks for the link. It showed that it does happen occasionally, especially at higher elevation. But it's quite rare under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computer languages do not worry about this unlikely problem (bits in the CPU randomly being changed by some outside force). Other forms of error are also not the applications area of responsibility, for example network data which is much more likely to be corrupted often has internal checks in the protocols to detect errors (checksums for example). The same is true for some storage.

In the rare environment where this really matters (space vehicles being the main one I know of) They have redundant applications running and compare the results of both to see if they match.

So in answer to you question these kind of issues are not the concern of the language, They are either handled at a lower level (checksums on network packets etc...), or a higher level (redundancy). Generally these kind of issues are only worried about in very rare circumstances such as space vehicles, nuclear power, etc...